# How to pass a Bitmap to PHP from Android

Tags: android, file-upload, http-post

I am allowing user to take a profile picture.  It then sets an ImageView.  After that I want to start an `AsyncTask` and upload image to server.  I already have several `PHP` classes in places to do this from several web apps I've done.

My question is, I don't know how to do the HttpPost part. I've done dozens of these with passing strings back and forth, not images.

I don't want to store the file in the database as a Blob.  My classes are setup to retrieve the file in `PHP`, name the file and move them into a location.  The File path is then stored in the server.

So if I have this:

```
photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

How to I pass `photo` to server through `HttpPost`? I've been many ways such as Mutilpart, Base64, etc.  Not sure best, modern approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Android side:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost post = new HttpPost( url );
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity( HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE );

entity.addPart( "theFile", new FileBody((( new File( filename ), mimeType ));

post.setEntity( entity );

client.execute( post );
```

Obviously, you'll need to set the mimeType and replaced "theFile" with a proper parameter. On the PHP side, this is just a regular file-upload.

Comment: Ok, thanks... I just need to find the right JAR's I guess for MultiPart.  The Oracle website isn't very straightforward. Aargh! Marking correct....

Comment: Pretty sure it's in HttpClient. My internet is a bit iffy right now, so I can't get to my repo.

Comment: Hey one more question, what do you use for mimeType normally? This will be specifically for Camera pictures or Gallery pictures.

Comment: Ah yes.. I do that in my PHP side, so maybe not necessary here?  I see a constructor without it...

Comment: Well, it's part of HTTP and Mime, so it would be good to include it for completeness, but it's not strictly necessary if you're controlling both sides of the conversation.